# Javascript in HTA File

Tags: javascript, vbscript, hta

everytime when i try to add javascript in a hta file with vbscript it comes an error message when i click the submit button:

```
object doesn't support this property or method
```

I try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
```

and this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       ...code
    </script>
```

Is there anyone who know the problem?

**//EDIT: I have the problem, i forgot a VBScript: to call the vbscript sub
THANKS!!**

```
<input type="submit" value=" Submit " onclick="Submit" style="margin-left:100px;">
```

This is the right one:

```
<input type="submit" value=" Submit " onclick="VBScript:Submit" style="margin-left:100px;">
```

Comment: Please show the full code of what you are trying to do. Also, you are talking about VBScript: Why are you specifying `text/javascript` as a type then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to be sure because your question is not complete, however it is likely that you are putting your Javascript code inside VBScripts `<script></script>` tags.

'' is like an opening bracket, and '' is like a closing bracket. The VBScript tags are only for VBScript and the Javascript ones are only for Javascript.

Put the following in SILLY.HTA and try it out:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Silly Application</title>
  <HTA:APPLICATION>
</head>
<body>
<script language="vbscript">
document.title = "NOT SO SILLY NOW"
self.ResizeTo 200,200

Sub Window_Onload
self.MoveTo (screen.availWidth - (document.body.clientWidth + 40)),10
End Sub
</script>

<script language="javascript">
window.resizeTo(640, 480);
document.write("<h1>Something from Javascript</h1>");
</script>
</body>
```