# HTA [javascript and vbscript] - Generic help on non-descript problem after code changes

Tags: javascript, vbscript, hta

I wrote an HTA that reads information out of a bunch of text files and displays the results to the screen using the following pseudo-logic:

- loop through a directory and add the content of each text file to an array
- loop through the array's 2 dimensional structure to build a table layout
- update itself using a setInterval timer

  I originally wrote it in purely vbscript/HTML which worked perfectly but then I needed a way to sort the displayed results by the third column or the array[x][2] value.

So I turned to javascript as it has much more friendly/quicker array usage.  I rewrote the functions so that the pseudo-logic looks like:

- loop through a directory and add the content of each text file to a JAVASCRIPT array
- SORT the JAVASCRIPT array by the array[x][2] idx
- Flatten the 2D JS array into a string using separators
- Split the sorted JS string into a VBS array and build table layout the exact same way
- update self using setInterval timer

after working out the syntax errors, the initial HTA load works perfectly as I'd intended it to.  But now, upon the setInterval() update, I get a generic JS error:

- Line: 1
- Char: 1
- Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
- Code: 0
- URL: file:///pathToHTA.hta

I've gone so far as to comment out the entire update function I'm using with setInterval() so that the function gets called but it doesn't actually do anything and I STILL get the error.

I'm at a loss as to where to go from here and am hoping someone might be able to give me some pointers as to what might be causing this error.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: so i ctrl-z'd through my script editor and got it all the way back to the original vbs code that works flawlessly.  i simply added the <script language="javascript"> section and all new JS functions from the new JS version but not using any of them and I get the same problem.  can anyone think of a reason that this error would be occurring on refresh?  because the js functions aren't being used and the error is getting thrown, i'd say it was syntax-related but then why does the initial page load work fine?

Comment: so i'm still back to my purely vbs version of the HTA and i have only added: <script type="text/javascript"> </script> and i am still getting the error.  i don't understand why the javascript tag itself is givine me this error...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158322/javascript-in-hta-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem:

For whatever reason, I had to switch the order of my script declarations.  In the original one with errors I was declaring my scripting in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   ...
</script>

<script type="text/vbscript">
   ...
</script>
```

The fix was that (for whatever reason), I had to flip-flop the delcarations.

I changed the order so that my vbscript functions were listed first and javascript ones second and this resolved the error.... anyone know why that would be?

Comment: I'm guessing your JavaScript was referencing a VBScript object (array or function).  The object didn't exist until you rearranged the order of script tags.

Comment: @harley.333 - yeah, that was one fo the things I'd assumed but I don't believe that to be the reason.  If it were, the initial load of the HTA should've failed instead of just the single function reference during the refresh.  Also, I would also get this error when JUST adding the <script type="text/javascript"> and closing </script> tag to the file with no actual javascript code in between them.  I know it doesn't make sense but I have a copy of my pure vbs version and I can reproduce the issue.  Anyways, thanks for taking the time to read the issue.